# Dynamic end-points

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, angular-fullstack

I have a UI component that generates a  mongo schema like this

```
{
    content: String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    author: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
}
```

the idea is take this schema and generate the end-point to get the info, the question is where do you recomend storage the schema in mongoDB or in the files somehow run programmatically

> yo angular-fullstack:endpoint mySchema

Thank You